# SharePoint 2016 Publishing Site with anonymous access asking for Credentials

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, iis, redirect, anonymous-access

I have a SharePoint publishing site with anonymous access with domain eg xxx.xxxxxxxx.com. Whenever I request the following URL it is asking me for credentials.

https://xxx.xxxxxxxx.com/EN/Pages

The above URL points to the pages which are Documents and Libraries. I don't want the site to ask for credentials for the above URL. The following will be my home page.
https://xxx.xxxxxxxx.com/EN/Pages/Default.aspx

So I don't want my SharePoint site to ask for credentials if the URL is pointing to Documents and Libraries. In this scenario I want the URL to be redirecting to the home page. Also, I don't want anonymous users to access the page library or any administrator features.

I have done some R&D on my part but haven't got any solution. Some suggested using **SharePoint:SpSecurityTrimmedControl** for hiding the elements for the anonymous users, but I don't think it is useful for what I want to achieve. Here is the link that suggested **SharePoint:SpSecurityTrimmedControl** https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sharepoint-developer/how-to-hide-login-prompt-for-sharepoint-2016-admin-url-s-via/m-p/354539

Below is the screenshot of what I don't want to show to the anonymous users.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When you request the URL https://xxx.xxxxxxxx.com/CN/Pages and the credentials box pops up, which means that anonymous users are trying to access the page library without the required permissions.

Please deactivate "Limited-access user permission lockdown mode" site collection feature to make anonymous users have permission to pages library.

[image]

Then you type the url https://xxx.xxxxxxxx.com/CN/Pages, there will be no login prompt.

In addition, SharePoint:SpSecurityTrimmedControl allows the conditional display of content depending on the user’s permission, but it cannot control the Windows credential box.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I don't what to give anonymous users permission to page library. As mentioned in my question I want to redirect them to the Home page.

Comment: Per my test URL redirect will not compliant on this issue.